# How to test a Jetpack Compose Composable containing rememberLauncherForActivityResult?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How can I test an Android Jetpack Compose composable that calls `rememberLauncherForActivityResult`?

For example:

```kotlin
import androidx.activity.compose.rememberLauncherForActivityResult
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.Text

@Composable
fun PickFileButton() {
  val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(CreateDocument("text/plain")) { 
    /* do something with the returned Uri */ 
  }
  Button(onClick={launcher.launch("default_file_name.txt")}) {
    Text("Pick File") 
  }
}
```

Clicking the button launches another activity that the user uses to pick a file.

A test would look like:

```kotlin
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.createComposeRule
import androidx.compose.ui.test.onNodeWithText
import androidx.compose.ui.test.performClick

class TestPickFileButton {
  @get:Rule val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

  @Test
  fun testPickFileButton() {
    composeTestRule.setContent { PickFileButton() }
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Pick File").performClick()
    // now Android CreateDocument activity has launched 
    // and "composeTestRule" cannot interact with this activity
    
    // rest of test eg to check the file was created
  }
}
```

I cannot complete the test because the external activity has been launched and I can't interact with this activity with the `ComposeContentTestRule` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution involves using [CompositionLocalProvider](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal) to override the default [ActivityResultRegistry](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultRegistry). This allows you to send a custom response with [ActivityResultRegistry.dispatchResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultRegistry#dispatchResult(int,O)) instead of launching an activity.

I had to read the source code for the [CreateDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument) contract to understand what kind of `Intent` was expected to be returned.

A working solution for this particular question is:

```kotlin
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.activity.compose.LocalActivityResultRegistryOwner
import androidx.activity.compose.rememberLauncherForActivityResult
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistryOwner
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalProvider
import androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.createComposeRule
import androidx.compose.ui.test.onNodeWithText
import androidx.compose.ui.test.performClick
import androidx.core.app.ActivityOptionsCompat
import androidx.core.net.toFile
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test

@Composable
fun PickFileButton() {
  val launcher =
      rememberLauncherForActivityResult(CreateDocument("text/plain")) {
        /* do something with the returned Uri */
      }
  Button(onClick = { launcher.launch("default_file_name.txt") }) { Text("Pick File") }
}

class TestPickFileButton {
  @get:Rule val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

  @Test
  fun testPickFileButton() {

    val testUri = Uri.parse("uri_string_to_return")

    composeTestRule.setContent {

      // ActivityResultRegistry is responsible for handling the 
      // contracts and launching the activity
      val registryOwner = ActivityResultRegistryOwner {
        object : ActivityResultRegistry() {
          override fun <I : Any?, O : Any?> onLaunch(
              requestCode: Int,
              contract: ActivityResultContract<I, O>,
              input: I,
              options: ActivityOptionsCompat?
          ) {
            // don't launch an activity, just respond with the test Uri
            val intent = Intent().setData(testUri)
            this.dispatchResult(requestCode, Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
          }
        }
      }

      CompositionLocalProvider(LocalActivityResultRegistryOwner provides registryOwner) {
        // any composable inside this block will now use our mock ActivityResultRegistry
        PickFileButton()
      }
    }


    composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Pick File").performClick()
    // no activity is launched, PickFileButton will received testUri as a respose.

    // rest of test eg to check the file was created
    assert(testUri.toFile().exists())
  }
}
```

Sources:
[Discussion in Kotlin Lang Slack Chat](https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/509519/how-do-you-mock-rememberlauncherforactivityresult-in-compose),
[ActivityResultRegistryTest's in Android repository](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:activity/activity-compose/src/androidTest/java/androidx/activity/compose/ActivityResultRegistryTest.kt;l=77),
[CompositionLocalProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#CompositionLocalProvider(kotlin.Array,kotlin.Function0))